# How to route network traffic of a host via another in the same LAN?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

So host A (mac OS) has ip: **10.1.10.65** and host B has ip: **10.1.10.68**, which is a linux Ubuntu in a virtual machine on host A.
I want to route all traffic from host A through host B.

What I have done so far is, I enabled ip forwarding on host B:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

and on host A:

```
route delete default
route add default 10.1.10.68
```

After these operations, I can browse Internet fine on host A, but i am really not certain that if all traffic has been routed through host B now.
I read some other posts and they have mentioned to use `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ethx -j MASQUERADE` on host B, I didn't use this command on host B but I am still able to reach internet fine on host A.
Am I missing something here? How do I tell that I have correctly routed traffic through host B? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Many people on the internet erronously think they need `iptables` for routing (which is a pet peeve of mine).

You can check the routing on host A with `ip route get a.b.c.d`, which will tell you where the next hop of IP `a.b.c.d` is according to the current rules.

You can also use `traceroute`, or `mtr` or similar to see the actual path the packets take (as long as the hosts they go through are not configured to prevent this).

BTW, `route` is the old command, `ip route ...` is the newer version, and some routing features of newer kernels will only be accessible with `ip route`.

Answer (score 0):

Run traceroute 8.8.8.8 on host A. The first hop will tell you what machine the traffic is going through.